# Making font bold for qi addons in elementor

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I have a process list in my wordpress website which I've built using the elementor plugin. And for the process list I've used another plugin "Qi addons for elementor". The [process](https://ibb.co/gTg3mb8) involves 3 stages and I've implemented it without any issue. You can see it in the [photo](https://ibb.co/gTg3mb8). But under the process number there are some texts. And my requirement is to make some of the lines bold. I tried applying `<b></b>` tag inside the text field but it didn't work. [Here's the UI](https://ibb.co/ngnKYDy) for the plugin where you can add or delete items.
Is there any other way to apply text bold effect to the selected lines?

Answer (score 1):

You should know that our Process Item does not allow html code within the widget text field. What you could do is to edit the plugin files for that specific widget, navigating to /wp-content/plugins/qi-addons-for-elementor/inc/shortcodes/process/templates/post-info/text.php and editing the line 4 where you would replace the existing esc_html() with wp_kses_post() function that should allow all HTML tags and attributes intact, please have a look at the screenshot below

[image: 1]

That will allow you to place html tags such as  to the text field within the widget-

Answer (score 0):

You could try `<strong></strong>` or: `<span style="font-weight: bold;"></span>`

Comment: I did but the tags are also showing in the preview mode